# Saving a high resolution image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, publish, tiff

I'm creating a scatterplot using ggplot in R (R version 3.2.1). I want to save the graph as a tiff image in 300 DPI in order to publish it in a journal. However, my code using ggsave or tiff() with dev.off doesn't seem to work and only saves it in 96 DPI. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Below is a sample of my code using both methods:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100

ddata <- data.frame(x,y)

library(ggplot2)

#using ggsave
ggplot(aes(x, y), data = ddata) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill = NA, fullrange=TRUE, color = "black")

ggsave("test.tiff", units="in", width=5, height=4, dpi=300, compression = 'lzw')

#using tiff() and dev.off
tiff('test.tiff', units="in", width=5, height=4, res=300, compression = 'lzw')

ggplot(aes(x, y), data = ddata) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, fill = NA, fullrange=TRUE, color = "black")

dev.off()
```

The output is a 96 DPI with a width of 1500 pixels and a height of 1200 pixels.

Comment: You might need to set height and width (and units)

Comment: The code works with simulated data! The problem should be at your plot, so a reproducible example is needed

Comment: Agreed. Works fine for me -- what are the pixel dimensions of your output, and what does ggplot say when you call `ggsave()`?

Answer (score 118):

You can do the following. Add your ggplot code after the first line of code and end with `dev.off()`.

```
tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=5, height=5, res=300)
# insert ggplot code
dev.off()
```

`res=300` specifies that you need a figure with a resolution of 300 dpi. The figure file named 'test.tiff' is saved in [your working directory](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/getwd).

Change `width` and `height` in the code above depending on the desired output.

Note that this also works for other `R` plots including `plot`, `image`, and `pheatmap`.

**Other file formats**

In addition to TIFF, you can easily use [other image file formats](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/png.html) including JPEG, BMP, and PNG. Some of these formats require less memory for saving.

Answer (score 38):

A simpler way is

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar)) + 
geom_point()

ggsave(path = path, width = width, height = height, device='tiff', dpi=700)
```